# Are there any IDEs with HTML5 IntelliSense support?

Tags: ide, html, intellisense

Are there any tools that show HTML5 tags inside IntelliSense?

What tools do you use to work with HTML5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Excellent IDE WebStorm supports exactly what you are looking for.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeZ0O.png)

[image]

Also see:

- [Enjoy HTML5 excitement with PhpStorm & WebStorm](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/webide/2010/06/enjoy-html5-excitement-with-phpstorm-webstorm/)

**Useful Resource:**

- [Dive into HTML5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/)

Comment: @4thpage: As you might have guessed by visiting their site, it is not free but it is worth buying as far as I am concerned :)

Comment: don't worry i get support from microsoft to work in both product VS 2010 or EW 4

Comment: @4thpage: I am not worrying :) Whatever you find useful :)

Answer (score 0):

Komodo Edit 6 has support for both HTML5 and CSS3. It's the free version of Komodo IDE.